# Hi I was wondering if anyone knows if my fish is pregnant or not?

Tags: fish, pregnancy

[image]

Hi I have had these fish for 2 months now and was wondering if it’s pregnant or ill or just it’s shape, the others are a lot thinner but i don’t know how to tell if it’s pregnant

Thanks for the help

Comment: It is hard to tell, but your fish looks like a guppy, in which case I am voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: They look like white clouds . if not some tetra . They are egg layers , not live bearers.